# How can I convert kbyte -> gbyte all values on same column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have log file like this:

```
...
h,7,0,0,0
h,8,0,0,0
h,9,1420617572,113390,9777
h,10,1420621172,546702,26577
h,11,1420621754,2746,2786
h,12,0,0,0
...
```

Last 2 column kbyte values. I need to update all last 2 column values kB to gB.

Any suggestion(awk,sed,etc.) for convert and update with column number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try something like this:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$NF=$NF/1024;$(NF-1)=$(NF-1)/1024}7' file
```

output:

```
h,7,0,0,0
h,8,0,0,0
h,9,1420617572,110.732,9.54785
h,10,1420621172,533.889,25.9541
h,11,1420621754,2.68164,2.7207
h,12,0,0,0
```

if you want to format the number a little bit:

```
kent$  awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$NF=sprintf("%.2f",$NF/1024);$(NF-1)=sprintf("%.2f",$(NF-1)/1024)}7' file
h,7,0,0.00,0.00
h,8,0,0.00,0.00
h,9,1420617572,110.73,9.55
h,10,1420621172,533.89,25.95
h,11,1420621754,2.68,2.72
h,12,0,0.00,0.00
```

Comment: I knew `1` for printing, but what does `7`?

Comment: @fredtantini `7` does same as `1`.

Comment: Thank you, it's work. I change 1024 to 1024/1024 for gb. Can I directly modify on file? If not, no problem, I can print temp and delete old file and move :).

Comment: @kent ok, it's evaluated to true…

Comment: @Ric you can do `awk '...' input > tmp && mv tmp input` oh, yes, `GB = 1024*1024*KB`, you need `/1024/1024` my bad.

Comment: just for info: if it's important use the correct Gb. On commercial value a Gb is 1000 * 1024 b and not 1024 * 1024 (for non IT understanding it's easier) so if it's for copying data on portable HD, maybe it is.